# Rails view path not being reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.3

> Given Rails 4.2, Ruby 2.3.1.

In theory, Rails should allow you to completely reset the view paths, as seen [here, in the source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ec28c4fb242a9bf0632bb4dac0d0a2d949eab1b3/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/view_paths.rb#L91).

However, when I reset the view_paths via `#view_paths=`, from a controller callback, something unexpected happens.

```
> view_paths.size
=> 2
> new_paths = view_paths.reject { |vp| rejection criteria }
> new_paths.size
=> 1
> view_paths = new_paths
> view_paths.size
=> 2
> _view_paths.size
=> 1
```

`self._view_paths` has successfully been reset, but `#view_paths` has not picked up those changes, despite [simply being a wrapper for `self._view_paths`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ec28c4fb242a9bf0632bb4dac0d0a2d949eab1b3/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/view_paths.rb#L82). Why is `self._view_paths` correct, and `#view_paths` not?

Note: This is important because Rails uses `#view_paths` when searching for view, not `self._view_paths`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like once a controller instance is created, the view path is accessed from the `lookup_context`, and that is where it needs to be changed.

```
 lookup_context.view_paths.paths.reject! { |vp| rejection criteria }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
view_paths = new_paths
```

to

```
self.view_paths = new_paths
```

`view_paths = new_paths` is most likely initializing a local variable called `view_paths` instead of calling the method `view_paths=`

Edit:

Since you are getting a `NoMethodError` you are not in the context you think you are in since there is a method with that name in the file you posted https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ec28c4fb242a9bf0632bb4dac0d0a2d949eab1b3/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/view_paths.rb#L91

Comment: `self.view_paths = new_paths` throws `NoMethodError: undefined method 'view_paths='`

Comment: Then that should tell you that you are not in the context you think you are in since there is a method with that name in the file you posted https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ec28c4fb242a9bf0632bb4dac0d0a2d949eab1b3/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/view_paths.rb#L91.

Comment: Good call on the context. If you update your answer I can change my down to an upvote. (SO has locked me changing my vote)

Comment: @steel if this solved your question, would you mind marking it as the answer. If not, let me know what you are missing.

Comment: The suggested answer throws an error. I was able to use another tack that I added as an answer.